# Best practice for initialising UITableViewCells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

New to swift. I have a custom `UITableViewCell` entitled `"MyTableViewCell"` code below:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
```

Should I be using `as!` or `as?` here to downcast? I read somewhere that it's not good practice to force downcast, though I see many people using it in other code examples.

Also I know Swift auto-infers the type but is it better to include that in declaration i.e.:

```
let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
```

Any pointers on this would be great. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about force downcasting/unwrapping being bad practice however in a case like this, its not really a bad thing to do.

You explicitly register the cell identifier `myCell` as an instance of the `MyTableViewCell` class either in your storyboard or via `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

This means that at build time, you know exactly that when you ask your tableView for a cell with the identifier of `myCell` that you are going to get back a `MyTableViewCell` cell. If you did make a mistake (maybe a typo) then your app is going to crash when you first test it at most. Something that you would pick up on while debugging thats not likely to become an issue in production.

Obviously, the compiler doesn't know about this hence you having to go behind it's back but it's nothing worth worrying about.

---

A bad time to force downcast stuff would be when you aren't at least 99.9% sure that by force downcasting/unwrapping isn't going to cause your app to crash. For example, maybe you are fetching a string out of a dictionary returned by a web service `let string = dictionary["myString"] as! String`. There are a bunch of scenarios where the key `myString` might not contain a Swift String (i.e JSON parser returned `NSNull`, they key wasn't there at all or it was not a String) so you should always make sure that you unwrap the value in a safe way.

Moral of the story is that you *should* try to avoid force downcasting/unwrapping where possible but there are some exceptions, this is one of them.

---

> though I see many people using it in other code examples.

You're right, you see a lot of people providing extremely poorly written Swift snippets on SO and lots of other people will simply just assume that its ok so it's good that you're questioning it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: So if you were using as? then you would do a check to make sure it's not nil and then execute code after. Is this correct?

Comment: @KexAri you'd use `as?` in conjunction with `if let` allowing you to safely unwrap the value in an if statement... I.e `if let string = dictionary["myString"] as? String {`... Although this wouldn't be suitable in the cell dequeue case because you **need** to return a non-optional cell in the function and that's something you wouldn't have in the else block, hence the force unwrapping

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) to be a handy resource for style guide stuff.

The section about [optionals](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#optionals) advises to:

> Declare variables and function return types as optional with ? where
>   a nil value is acceptable.
>
> Use implicitly unwrapped types declared with ! only for instance
>   variables that you know will be initialized later before use, such as
>   subviews that will be set up in viewDidLoad.

On [type inference](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#type-inference):

> Prefer compact code and let the compiler infer the type for a constant or variable, unless you need a specific type other than the default such as CGFloat or Int16.

Of course, if your app is really mission critical and you truly need type safety then you'd probably want to ignore that piece of advice and make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If the cell is designed in Interface Builder, you definitely know that it exists and forced downcast is absolutely safe.

The type annotation `let cell: MyTableViewCell` is syntactic sugar and not necessary as the compiler can infer the type